# Grails: User Avatar Uploader

Tags: grails, upload, image-uploading

I have profiles for every user in my Grails Application and want them to be able to upload profile pictures. Therefore I made an uploadForm in the view:

```
<g:img dir="tmp" file="1.jpg"/>
<g:uploadForm action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <input type="submit" />
</g:uploadForm>
```

As you can see I just want to display the profile picture of the user with `ID = 1`.

The upload action:

```
def upload() {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if (f.empty) {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        render(view: 'uploadForm')
        return
    }
    f.transferTo(new File('/tmp/'+springSecurityService.currentUser.id+'.jpg'))
    flash.message = 'file in /tmp/'+springSecurityService.currentUser.id+'.jpg'
    redirect action: 'edit', id: springSecurityService.currentUser.id
}
```

My Problem is, that the profile picture of the user with `ID = 1` doesn't show up. I checked, that it has the correct value (`ID = 1`).

In my stack trace I have the following:

> | ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /tmp/1.jpg

Why can't it find the data? I have saved it in the upload action.

Comment: are you saying the picture isn't saved, or you can't view it on the browser after it's saved?

Comment: It isnt saved in the filesystem...

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the file to the /tmp folder in the file system. Unless you have given proper permissions to the folder, you will not be able to save to this.

More importantly, the g:img tag searches for the file in the tmp folder under the web-apps folder of your grails application - and it will never find the file there since you are not saving it there.